# Magento sessions not working on server, but work on localhost

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In my Observer.php I am storing a variable in the session

```
  $itemAddedToCart = 'true';
  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setItemAddedToCart($itemAddedToCart);
```

When I try to retrieve it:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getItemAddedToCart();
```

It is always NULL.
The weird thing is it works fine in my local dev environment (MAMP).  Why isn't it working on a server?  Tried on both Dreamhost and a Magento Hosting company.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: More info: I think it has something to do with Case-insensitivity and a file not being loaded correctly.  I am able to get the session to work in a different file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being an issue with Case sensitivity.
On my Mac, things works fine because mac ignores case of folders/file.
On a linux server it failed to work because linux uses a case sensitive file system.

In my case, in the config.xml I had to change the class node from this:

```
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
               <mymodule_modulator_model_observer>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>Mymodule_Modulator_Model_Observer</class>
```

To this:

```
<class>MyModule_Modulator_Model_Observer</class>
         ^Changed to upper case to match folder name
```